# Reversal of the number triangle[c]

Tags: c

I have this code where it ask the user for a range and it outputs a number triangle. For example, if inputs 4, the code does this:

```
   1
  121
 12321
1234321
```

The problem is the decrement of the code. I have tried to reverse the code, but that didn't turn out well because it outputted `1`.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  

main(){  
  int i,j,k,l,n;  
  printf("enter the range=");  
  scanf("%d",&n);  
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++){  
    for(j=1;j<=n-i;j++) {  
      printf(" ");
    }  
    for(k=1;k<=i;k++){
      printf("%d",k);  
    }  
    for(l=i-1;l>=1;l--){  
      printf("%d",l);  
    }  
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Is there any function or way so I could have an output like this?

```
   1
  121
 12321
1234321
 12321
  121
   1
```

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment. What have you tried?  In fact that looks pretty easy.

Comment: I copied my main for loop and reversed the condition on it, but that outputted only `1`. @zipzit

Comment: So show the code you tried.

Comment: Oh, I deleted it cause it didn't work. @zipzit

Comment: Here's a hint. Have you considered two for loops?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean can you car to explain @zipzit

Comment: Okay try this. Attempt to add a comment to each of your for loops. Describe EXACTLY what that loop does. Remark out that section to verify that it does exactly what you thing it does.  When you understand what is happening you can then write code to perform additional features.

Comment: ok then, i will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code but I recommend learn to how this code work

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main(){  
  int i,j,k,l,n,space;
  printf("enter the range=");  
  scanf("%d",&n);  
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++){  
    for(j=1;j<=n-i;j++) {  
      printf(" ");
    }  
    for(k=1;k<=i;k++){
      printf("%d",k);  
    }  
    for(l=i-1;l>=1;l--){  
      printf("%d",l);  
    }  
    printf("\n");
  }

      for(i=n-1;i>=1;i--)
        {
    for(j=1;j<=n-i;j++) {  
      printf(" ");
    }  
    for(k=1;k<=i;k++){
      printf("%d",k);  
    }   
      for(l=i-1;l>=1;l--){  
      printf("%d",l);  
    }
    printf("\n");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a matter of making an inverted copy your main`for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` loop. Currently your for loop goes from 1 to n. You should copy that loop and make it go from n-1 to 1. I leave to you the exercise of understanding why you should start at n-1, and how to reverse the direction of your loop.

To avoid unnecessary duplication of code, you could isolate the code inside your for loop in a different function and call it from inside your loops.